# Remove border when tracing image - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, shapes, image-trace

I am trying to create a vector image in Illustrator to be used with a laser cutter.

The process i use is open the image - select it - Image Trace with default settings - Expand - Ungroup. I then go into Layers and deselect the main image so i am just left with the below. Save as SVG.

The problem i am having is I always end up with a square border which i presume is the original canvas size of the image. Trouble is my laser wants to cut this.

[image: Illistrator screenshot]

Am i doing something wrong when tracing the image or is there a way to remove this border, if i deselect it in the layers it also removes the outer circle

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do your trace, open the Image trace panel

Hit the *Advanced* drop down

Check the *Ignore White* option

[image]

When you do *Object > Expand*, you should be able to see you have outlines of the object only, without the background being included.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, works a treat. I would upvote the answer but i dont have enough reputation :-(

Comment: @Pigsfoot Mark it as correct by clicking the arrow next to the answer. It'll give you both reputation points.

Answer (score 3):

What Billy Kerr said, or

- hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>
- hit <kbd>A</kbd>
- click at any location on the square box to select that shape
- hit <kbd>DEL</kbd> two times